# Convert Javascript Confirm to Jquery confirm in a button item of ASPX GridView

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this code and need to change the JavaScript confirm to a Jquery confirm action.

With Jquery I have a Callback function that will be executed when user press OK button. How can I catch the OK action from Jquery confirm dialog? I mean, I need to send a "return true" to OnClientClick in order to execute OnCommand.

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGridView" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Close" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server"
                    CommandName="SendInfo"
                    OnClientClick="confirm('Are you sure?');"  
                    OnCommand="ExecuteTaskCodeBehind"
                    Style="cursor: pointer">
                        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think it sounds like, if you get 'OK', you want to trigger the linkbutton's click event:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">
    LinkButton
</asp:LinkButton>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<br />
<input type="button" onclick="triggerclick();" value="trigger click" />
<br />
<script>
    function triggerclick() {
        if (confirm("trigger click?")) {
            document.getElementById("LinkButton1").click();
        }
    }
</script>
```

code behind:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label3.Text = "clicked";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but the problem is that the link button is generated dynamically when other process fills the grid. And the document.getElementById("LinkButton1").click(); can't be run because I don't have the ID of the link button, and if I tried to debug and get the one assigned in runtime, I got an error that the Id is not defined.

Comment: I thought that might be a problem. LinkButtons create anchor tags. Can you find it by `$("a")`, or nth child, or similar?

Comment: I will try the nth child. Thank you very much.